# javascript implementation of java.util.calendar api

Tags: java, javascript, api, calendar, momentjs

Is there a javascript equivalent implementation of `java.util.Calendar` API?  It will be quite handy to do date manipulation with it around.

Comment: I had to build a complex scheduling system with the Java Calendar API a couple years ago. I will admit it is powerful and sophisticated but mainly, it is a big pain in the ass. It is way to complicated for your average date/time calculations. I just can't believe others are looking for a similar API for different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though not exact http://momentjs.com/ is much better in many ways ! I would go for this if given a choice.

### Formatting dates

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
moment().format('dddd');
moment().format("MMM Do YY");
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');
moment().format();

September 23rd 2012, 1:29:09 am
Sunday
Sep 23rd 12
2012 escaped 2012
2012-09-23T01:29:09+01:00
```

### Timeago

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();

11 months ago
3 months ago
an hour ago
in a day
28 minutes ago
```

### Calendar Time

```
moment().subtract('days', 10).calendar();
moment().subtract('days', 6).calendar();
moment().subtract('days', 3).calendar();
moment().subtract('days', 1).calendar();
moment().calendar();
moment().add('days', 1).calendar();
moment().add('days', 3).calendar();
moment().add('days', 10).calendar();

09/12/2012
last Sunday at 12:06 PM
last Wednesday at 12:06 PM
Yesterday at 12:06 PM
Today at 12:06 PM
Tomorrow at 12:06 PM
Tuesday at 12:06 PM
```

### Internationalization

```
moment().format('L');
moment().format('LL');
moment().format('LLL');
moment().format('LLLL');

09/22/2012
September 22 2012
September 22 2012 12:07 PM
Saturday, September 22 2012 12:07 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

[YUI 2: Calendar](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/), I think is a similar to what you are looking for..

Also a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) would get you many answers.

Comment: That's a calendar widget, not a library for performing computations involving dates and times.

Comment: @Mike Samuel - Agree, added a link which has many answers playing with date in js..